# arrangement of input items in ui.R as a table?

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on an app that has the user input a 2x2 table. Currently i am using the ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("2x2 Table"),
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(                                      
       sliderInput("n11","Count of cell 1-1",
          min=0, max=100, value=50,step=1), 
       sliderInput("n12","Count of cell 1-2",
          min=0, max=100, value=50,step=1), 
       sliderInput("n21","Count of cell 2-1",
          min=0, max=100, value=50,step=1), 
       sliderInput("n22","Count of cell 2-2",
          min=0, max=100, value=50,step=1), 
    ),
  mainPanel(
      uiOutput("table")
    )
  )
))
```

but it would be much nicer if i could have a 2x2 table in the sidebarPanel where the user enters their numbers

I found matrixInput but that does not seem to work, one can not change the matrix interactively

Thanks

Wolfgang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into using nested `fluidRow` and columns to get the required grid rather than sidebarLayout & sidebarPanel. Example is below... may need to copy and pasted into R

```
library(shiny);
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Word Prediction - Iteration 1.12"),
    fluidRow(
        column(3,
               wellPanel(
                   h4('Work outstanding'),
                )
               ),
        column(9,
               fluidRow(column(9,h4('Predicted words ...'))),
               fluidRow(
                   column(3,
                          verbatimTextOutput('oid1'),
                          tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", "#oid1 {text-align: center}"))
                          ),
                   column(3,
                          verbatimTextOutput('oid2'),
                          tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", "#oid2 {text-align: center}"))
                          ),
                   column(3,
                          verbatimTextOutput('oid3'),
                          tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", "#oid3 {text-align: center}"))
                          )
                   ),
               fluidRow(
                   column(9,
                      h4('The same sentence now including the predicted word ...'),
                      verbatimTextOutput('oid4')
                   )
               ),
               br(),br(),br(),br(),hr(),
               fluidRow(
                   column(9,
                          textInput('id1','Type in your sentence'),
                          tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", "#id1 {width: 720px}"))
                          )
                )
           )
    )
))
```